# Combine geom_point with geom_line for replicates

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a melted data frame that I plot as a facet_wrap with geom_point. I would like to combine the points with lines where the line goes between the same `Id`. Please see my data below and my command:

```
mydata
Replicate   Id      Gene          Timepoint           value
rep1        miR1_1  miR1           s1               4.2
rep2        miR1_2  miR1           s2               2.3
rep1        miR1_3  miR1           s1               2.3
rep2        miR1_4  miR1           s2               4.3
rep1        miR1_5  miR1           s1               6.3
rep2        miR1_6  miR1           s2               6.3
rep1        miR2_1  miR2           s1               7.2
rep2        miR2_2  miR2           s2               7.3
rep1        miR2_3  miR2           s1               6.3
rep2        miR2_4  miR2           s2               5.3
rep1        miR2_5  miR2           s1               2.3
rep2        miR2_6  miR2           s2               4.3

ggplot(mydata,aes(Timepoint,value,colour=Replicate))  + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~Gene,ncol=4)
```

This is what I want:

[image]

Comment: The example plot is a bit confusing: no facets, error bars (where do they come from your data?). Could you please elaborate? Preferrably with a picture that is related to your data.

Comment: The example plot was just to show the lines. Mine does not have error bars and consist of several plots in a facet format.

Comment: Okay, you say that you want to connect points with the same id, but there's not a single collision of ids in your data sample.